# Modifying all classes which implemented by interface

Tags: java, c#, design-patterns

Lets say I have an interface like

```
interface IMessage
{
    void DoSomething();
    void DoAnother();
}
```

Lets say in a big project 100 classes implemented this interface. But if I add a new method to IMessage interface like Foo();

```
interface IMessage
{
   void DoSomething();
   void DoAnother();
   void Foo();
}
```

So my other 100 classes which implement this interface has to change.
 So does something wrong here? Changing all clasess? I hear about Open Close prensible so I used interface but in that situation, what is the logic?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking. Yes, if you add a method to the interface, you need to add an implementation to all classes implementing the interface.

Comment: If you have a scenerio involving adding new methods in future, you should consider using abstract classes instead, so that you will not need to change all the classes each time.

Comment: Perhaps create an IExtendedMessage interface which itself extends IMessage. Add your Foo method to the IExtendedMessage interface and any code which uses IMessage should be fine.

Comment: if you have written 100 classes that all implement IMessage and you then decide IMessage needs to have another method you are a either a fast typer or your 100 classes don't need the foo() method

Answer (score 4):

Java 8 introduces "default" methods for interfaces; this means that you can provide a "default" implementation. This allows you to extend existing interfaces without adapting all implementing classes.

But if you are working older versions of Java - you nailed it: then you have to update all your classes.

And hopefully a final edit: modern IDEs are able to generate such "missing" methods for you; and depending on the complexity of what "Foo()" should do ... it might not be so much work in the end.

But there is one other option:

Instead of adding a new method to your existing interface, you could do

```
interface IMessageV2 extends IMessage {
   void Foo();
}
```

This allows you to decide for each of your classes if you want to "update" the class to implement IMessage **or** IMessageV2. But of course, for those classes that you change to implement IMessageV2; you have to provide an implementation for any new method in that "new" interface.

The downside of this approach is that sooner or later, your client code will have to deal with objects that implement the V1, V2, V3, ... version of the interface. This can turn nasty, too.

Answer (score 1):

**Depends**

Do you need this new `void Foo()` method in all the 100 classes.?

If Yes, then there is no other way and this is not wrong.

But if you want a similar interface but don't want those classes to have the change then write another interface

```
interface IMessageChild extends IMessage
{
   void Foo();
}
```